# Why there is a x mark on Servers folder in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

[image]

I made a simple dynamic web project.
To run project, I added server Tomcat.
I don't know why there is a x mark on Servers folder.
please help me to fix it.
Thank you.

Comment: Looks in the Problems view to see if there is a message

Comment: It's an icon that represents an XML file, and there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @saka1029 the red mark on the Servers folder, not the xml icon.

Comment: @greg-449 I reinstall tomcat and the mark's removed, maybe the tomcat I installed has error thank you